# Javascript image not stopping at edge of window

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to move an image with arrow keys in Javascript, AND prevent it from moving off screen. The code seems to work for preventing the left side, but not the right. Here is my code. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            *{
                margin:0; 
                padding:0;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            html, body{
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onkeydown="checkKey();">
        <img id="player" src="left.gif" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var image = document.getElementById('player');

            image.style.left = '0px'; 
            image.style.position= 'relative'; 

            function checkKey(event){
                event = event || window.event;
                var keycode = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
                if(keycode === 39){
                    moveRight();
                }
                if(keycode === 37){
                    moveLeft();
                }
            }

            if (image.style.left < screen.width + 'px'){
                image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left,10) + 10 + 'px';
            }

            function moveLeft(){
                if (image.style.left > 0 + 'px'){
                    image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left, 10) - 10 + 'px';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get the dimension of screen and apply a condition if image.style.right should be less than screen width and for left image.style.left should be greater than 0

Comment: @shadow Thanks for the answer, but when I added this condition, the image stopped moving at 20px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this | **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jCKpd/7/)**

```
var image;
window.onload=function(){
image = document.getElementById('player');
image.style.left = '0px'; 
image.style.position= 'relative';  
}

function checkKey(event)
{
  event = event || window.event;
  var keycode = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
  if(keycode === 39)
   {
    moveRight();
   }
  if(keycode === 37)
   {
    moveLeft();
   }
}

function moveLeft()
 {
   if (parseInt(image.style.left) > 0)
   {
    image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left, 10) - 10 + 'px';
   }
 }
function moveRight()
 {
    var parentWidth = image.parentNode.offsetWidth;
   if (parseInt(image.style.left)+image.offsetWidth <parentWidth)
   {
    image.style.left = parseInt(image.style.left, 10) + 10 + 'px';
   }
 }
```